# hibernate delete many-to-many association

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, many-to-many

I am having a Store class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Store")
public class Store {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ST_Name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

        ...

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="store")
    private Set<StoreProductLink> products = new HashSet<StoreProductLink>();

    public void addProduct(Product pr, int quantity, String lt) {
        StoreProductLink link = new StoreProductLink();

        ...

        this.products.add(link);
        pr.getStores().add(link);
    }

    public void removeProduct(Product pr) {
        StoreProductLink link = new StoreProductLink();

        ....

        this.products.remove(link);
        pr.getStores().remove(link);
    }
```

and a Product class

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ProductPK.class)
@Table(name = "Product")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PR_Name", nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PR_SerialNumber", nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String serialNumber;

    ....

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="product")
    private Set<StoreProductLink> stores = new HashSet<StoreProductLink>();
```

and the class StoreProductLink which is the join table

```
@Entity
@IdClass(StoreProductLinkPK.class)
@Table(name = "StoreProductLink")
public class StoreProductLink {

    @Id
    private String storeName;

    @Id
    private String productName;

    @Id
    private String productSerialNumber;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private int quantity;

    @Column(name = "lt")
    private String lt;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "storeName", updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "ST_Name")
    private Store store;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns(value = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "productName", updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "PR_Name"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "productSerialNumber", updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "PR_Serialnumber") })
    private Product product;
```

.

```
Store store = new Store();
Product product = new Product();
product.setName(example);
...
store.addProduct(product, 5, "com");
updateHibernateFunction(store); (this inserts in StoreProductLink table this --> storeName,example, exampleSerialNumber,5,com)
```

Doing

```
store.removeProduct(product);
```

this function removes the product example from the Set named products.
And the

```
t1 = entityManager.merge(t);
```

returns a store having a products Set without the product example.

```
updateHibernateFunction(store);
```

However the StoreProductLink table is still having the record.

Add operation works fine. Delete operation doesn't work. :/

**ADDED**

This is the update function

```
public T update(T t) 
    {
        EntityManager entityManager = DataLayer.getEntityManager();
        T t1 = null;

    EntityTransaction tx = null;

    try
    {
        tx = entityManager.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        t1 = entityManager.merge(t);
        tx.commit();
    }catch(RuntimeException e)
    {
        if(tx != null && tx.isActive()) tx.rollback();
        throw e;
    }finally
    {
        entityManager.close();
    }

    return t1;
}
```

Comment: Do some reading on the `@Cascade` annotation... Been a few months since I did anything with Hibernate but I think you want CascadeOnDelete

Comment: I have in both classes on @OneToMany annotation the (cascade = CascadeType.ALL). Should I add anything else?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a matter of cascade, because cascade means (in the DELETE case): "delete the target when you delete me".

Try the `orphanRemoval`:

```
public class Product {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="product",
        orphanRemoval=true)
    private Set<StoreProductLink> stores = new HashSet<StoreProductLink>();
```

Comment: Unfortunately the problem still remains.

Comment: I wonder... could it be because there is still a connection to the other side of the relationship (the `Store`)?

Comment: I can not understand why this is happening. 
Doing
    store.addProduct(product1);
    store.removeProduct(product2);
    updateHibernateFunction(store);
only adds the product1. Doesn't remove product2.